# Obtain .NET PublicKeyToken from snk file?

Tags: .net

How to obtain the PublicKeyToken from an snk file? Using command line tools. I thought about using sn.exe, however, couldn't find a suiting parameter.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to use the `sn.exe` tool:

```
sn -p yourkey.snk publickey.snk
```

now there is the publickey.snk with only the public key

```
sn -tp publickey.snk
```

now you have both the public key and the public key token.

---

Given a `byte[]` cotnaining the snk file, like

```
byte[] snk = File.ReadAllBytes("YourSnkFile.snk");
```

use

```
byte[] publicKey = GetPublicKey(snk);
byte[] publicKeyToken = GetPublicKeyToken(publicKey);
```

with these utility methods

```
public static byte[] GetPublicKey(byte[] snk)
{
    var snkp = new StrongNameKeyPair(snk);
    byte[] publicKey = snkp.PublicKey;
    return publicKey;
}

public static byte[] GetPublicKeyToken(byte[] publicKey)
{
    using (var csp = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] hash = csp.ComputeHash(publicKey);

        byte[] token = new byte[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            token[i] = hash[hash.Length - i - 1];
        }

        return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Thanks +1

Comment: Just for information, It's working only in windows for net4x, and raise `System.PlatformNotSupportedException` in netcore

Comment: @M.Hassan Sadly you are right. There is an open issue about this (https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/4896), but it is only on documentation.

Answer (score 26):

Two steps are required to extract Public Key Token from .snk file using the [sn.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Extract the Public Key from `YourFile.snk` using sn.exe and write it to `Token.snk`

> sn -p YourFile.snk Token.snk

Extract the Public Key Token from `Token.snk` using sn.exe and write it to `PublicToken.txt`

> sn -t Token.snk > PublicToken.txt

Comment: @specializt. Who said that he needs a programming solution? `How to obtain the PublicKeyToken from an snk file? Using command line tool...`

Comment: Don't know why but this resulted in a much shorted key than I was expecting... @Ivan G. s PowerShell solution gave me back what I needed.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles on this "sn -tp Token.snk" gives the token and the actual public key

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @xanatos answer, PowerShell version if anyone needs it:

```
function Get-SnkPublicKey([string]$FilePath)
{
    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
    $pair = New-Object System.Reflection.StrongNameKeyPair -ArgumentList @(,$bytes)
    $publicKey = $pair.PublicKey

    #[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($publicKey)
    $hexes = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($publicKey);
    $hexes.Replace("-", "")
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, but it prints the full public key and not its token

Answer (score 1):

Since StrongNameKeyPair is not available in net5.0 or netstandard2.1 and since sn.exe requires Administrator privileges yoy may use the class RSACryptoServiceProvider instead:

```
$bytes = Get-Content "YOUR-PROJECT.snk" -AsByteStream
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.ImportCspBlob($bytes)

$publicKey = $rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey()
$privateKey = $rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey()
```

```
static void Main()
{
  byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("YOUR-PROJECT.snk");
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new();

  rsa.ImportCspBlob(bytes);

  byte[] publicKey = rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey();
  byte[] privateKey = rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey();
}
```